# how to access to "$(this)" object from event handler passed to "on" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When Event Handler set a not anonymous function, then error occurred by accessing to `$(this)` object.

```
function TextBoxChangeEventHandler(id)
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    //...do something
}

$("#object_position :input[type='text']")
    .on("change", function(){TextBoxChangeEventHandler("id");});
//other some object set TextBoxChangeEventHandler...
```

Error log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Replace `function(){TextBoxChangeEventHandler();}` with `TextBoxChangeEventHandler`

Comment: sorry, I editted code. exactly, I pass the argument.

Comment: Your update actually makes all answers incorrect. It's not good to do such updates, you know... But nevertheless: why do you want to pass string "id" to function?

Comment: I want to also set other elements to this event handler.
use to id, I branch process slightly behaviour difference.

Comment: Okay, let us assume that "id" really should be sent. Then right now Arun P Johny's answer looks like correct one.

Comment: It was a great help. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass a custom execution context

```
function TextBoxChangeEventHandler() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //...do something
}

$("#object_position :input[type='text']").on("change", function () {
    TextBoxChangeEventHandler.call(this);
    //with the update
    TextBoxChangeEventHandler.call(this, 'id');
});
```

Comment: Just to mention: for updated version it should be `function TextBoxChangeEventHandler(id) {`.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
function TextBoxChangeEventHandler(elem)
{
    var value = $(elem).val();
    //...do something
}

$("#object_position :input[type='text']")
    .on("change", function(){TextBoxChangeEventHandler(this);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `TextBoxChangeEventHandler` function by reference.

```
$("#object_position :input[type='text']").on("change", TextBoxChangeEventHandler);
```

Comment: Even though there is strange update of question, this answer is what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference to `TextBoxChangeEventHandler` to your method. So for example,

```
  $("#object_position :input[type='text']").on("change", TextBoxChangeEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery proxy for this -

```
$("#object_position :input[type='text']")
    .on("change", $.proxy(TextBoxChangeEventHandler("id"),this));
```

Comment: `TextBoxChangeEventHandler("id")` will return `undefined`, then `$.proxy(undefined, this)` will be executed.

Comment: @Regent -Got your point .So this will be the working once avoiding the issue of undefined - `$("#object_position :input[type='text']")
    .on("change", $.proxy(TextBoxChangeEventHandler,this));`